# Does Heroku run Docker containers in Swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

I'm running my Docker app on Heroku, using the `heroku.yml` file to define the app. My `heroku.yml` [file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) pretty much mirrors my `docker-compose.yml` file that I use locally.

1) Does Heroku subsequently run my app in swarm mode, i.e. using multiple Docker engines or just one?

2) What would be the performance differences if it ran my app in swarm mode vs. not?